# Length mismatch error when scaling up multiIndex slicer on large dataset

Tags: python, csv, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to split imported csv files (timeseries) and manipulated them, using pandas MultiIndex Slicer command `.xs()`. The following `df` replicates the structure of my imported csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Sensor ID': [14,1,3,14,3],
    'Building ID': [109,109,109,109,109],
    'Date/Time': ["26/10/2016 14:31:14","26/10/2016 14:31:16", "26/10/2016 14:32:17", "26/10/2016 14:35:14", "26/10/2016 14:35:38"],
    'Reading': [20.95, 20.62, 22.45, 20.65, 22.83],
    })

df.set_index(['Sensor ID','Date/Time'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df)

SensorList = [1, 3, 14]

for s in SensorList:
    df1 = df.xs(s, level='Sensor ID')
```

I have tested the code on a small excerpt of csv data and it works fine. However, when implementing with the entire csv file, I receive the error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 19562 elements, new values have 16874 elements`.

Printing `df.info()` returns the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 65981 entries, (1, 2016-10-26 14:35:15) to (19, 2016-11-07 11:27:14)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Building ID    65981 non-null int64
Reading        65981 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 1.5+ MB
None
```

Any tip on what may be causing the error?

**EDIT**

I inadvertently truncated my code, thus leaving it pointless in its current form. The original code resamples values into 15-minutes and 1-hour intervals.

with:

```
units = ['D1','D3','D6','D10']
unit_output_path = './' + unit + '/'
```

the loop does:

```
for s in SensorList:

    ## Slice multi-index to isolate all readings for sensor s
    df1 = df_mi.xs(s, level='Sensor ID')
    df1.drop('Building ID', axis=1, inplace=True)

    ## Resample by 15min and 1hr intervals and exports individual csv files
    df1_15min = df1.resample('15Min').mean().round(1)
    df1_hr = df1.resample('60Min').mean().round(1)
```

**Traceback:**

```
File "D:\AN6478\AN6478_POE_ABo.py", line 52, in <module>
    df1 = df_mi.xs(s, level='Sensor ID')
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1736, in xs
    setattr(result, result._get_axis_name(axis), new_ax)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2685, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas\src\properties.pyx", line 65, in pandas.lib.AxisProperty.__set__ (pandas\lib.c:44748)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 428, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2635, in set_axis
    (old_len, new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 19562 elements, new values have 16874 elements
```

Comment: What is your desired final outcome? Perhaps there is no need for a loop here. And where does the error actually occur - can you provide the traceback? At moment, your code overwrites `df1` within each loop.

Comment: @pansen I have edited my question to include commands performed under the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why exactly `df1 = df_mi.xs(s, level='Sensor ID')` raises the ValueError here. Where does `df_mi` come from?

Here is an alternative using [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) which accomplishes what you want on your given dummy data frame without relying on multiIndex and `xs`. :

```
# reset index to have DatetimeIndex, otherwise resample won't work
df = df.reset_index(0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# create data frame for each sensor, keep relevant "Reading" column
grouped = df.groupby("Sensor ID")["Reading"]

# iterate each sensor data frame
for sensor, sub_df in grouped:
    quarterly = sub_df.resample('15Min').mean().round(1)
    hourly = sub_df.resample('60Min').mean().round(1)

    # implement your to_csv saving here
```

Note, you could also use the `groupby` on the multiIndex with `df.groupby(level="Sensor ID")`, however since you want to resample later on, it is easier to drop *Sensor ID* from the multiIndex which simplifies it overall.

Comment: I wished I could have the multi-index slice working, but this solution is also suitable for my data. Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned, you can use `df.groupby(level="Sensor ID")` to groupby on a multiIndex. This works perfectly fine. In addition, you may try the [pd.IndexSlice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers). For example, `df_mi.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 14], "Reading"]`.